# Replace all commas with periods and vice versa in a string?

Tags: java, string, kotlin, java-stream, sequence

Trying to figure out how to do this in one pass using Kotlin sequences if possible. I don't think number formatting based on Locale is possible since I sometimes have strings that would throw NumberFormatException like 1. or 1, . Need to do this without any number transformations.

- 12,345.6789 -> 12.345,6789
- 12.345,6789 -> 12,345.6789
- . -> ,
- 1. -> 1,

Comment: @Eugene How? "12,345.6789".replaceAll(",", ".") would give me "12.345.6789" ?

Comment: right, I provided an answer

Comment: @nicoqueijo - You can use `String::replace`. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61162001/replace-all-commas-with-periods-and-vice-versa-in-a-string/61162799#61162799).

Comment: Where is the string coming from?  Presumably it started off as a number; is there any option for changing how it's converted to a string in the first place, to avoid messing about with it later?

Comment: Regarding your question that you posted on Software Engineering about your Github page, you should submit a DMCA Takedown Notice to Google Play: https://support.google.com/legal/troubleshooter/1114905

Comment: See also https://help.github.com/en/github/site-policy/github-terms-of-service#5-license-grant-to-other-users

Answer (score 2):

In one pass. Not using any Kotlin, I can write only Java.

```
    String s = "12,345.6789";
    char[] ca = s.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        if (ca[i] == '.') {
            ca[i] = ',';
        } else if (ca[i] == ',') {
            ca[i] = '.';
        }
    }
    s = new String(ca);
    System.out.println(s);
```

Output:

> 12.345,6789

It’s pretty low-level, so please wrap it into a method with a nice name. Otherwise I think it’s straight-forward. If you prefer to use a `StringBuffer` or `StringBuilder`, those are options too.

I’d giver number parsing and formatting one more thought if that was me, though.

Comment: "those are options too" but they don't confer any particular advantage, considering you are simply changing character values (as opposed to inserting or deleting).

Comment: @AndyTurner hitting implementation details here, but with the reference implementation and Java 9 or newer, using a `StringBuilder` bears the potential to perform the entire operation with one byte per char instead of two. In contrast, using a `char[]` not only lacks this potential, it requires the `String` constructor to check whether the array contains non-latin-1 characters.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `map` function on a `String` and convert the resulting `List<Char>` with `joinToString()`. It's one pass for replacement, but it has to be copied back into a String.

```
fun String.swapCommasAndDots() = map { c ->
    when (c) {
        ',' -> '.'
        '.' -> ','
        else -> c
    }
}.joinToString("")
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be a very naive solution but if you know you'll only have numbers in your string this would work.

```kotlin
var oldString = "12,345.6789"
var newString = oldString
    .replace('.', 'x')
    .replace(',', '.')
    .replace('x', ',')
print(newString)
// 12.345,6789
```

Comment: I really don't see how's your solution easier.

Comment: easier in the sense that it _would not break_ if  `x` is present in input; unlike yours. easier to reason about, is what I meant.

Comment: Sure, but I think he was asking for a simple solution for his use-case. Therefore, I see no point in instantiating 3 objects and going through a while loop.

Comment: From what I understood reading the question, strings are represented by numbers, commas and periods. Therefore, I see no problem with simplifying the solution. :)

Comment: well, in such a case - do not iterate so many times the input, iterate the char array once and build a new String. Well, I guess someone [just did](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61162481/1059372)

Comment: "instantiating 3 objects". You are instantiating four intermediate objects, just hidden withing the `replace` calls. But the most expensive aspect is the copying of the entire string contents during the operation, which happens three times here and only one time in the other solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could replace one character with something not used:

```
String str = "1234.123213,414";
str = str.replace(",", "+");
str = str.replace(".", ",");
str = str.replace("+", ".");
System.out.println("str = " + str); 
// Output: str = 1234,123213.414
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code for that purpose:-

```
String num = "12,345.6789";
//Replacing all '.' to '}' Just for the sake of simplicity
String transformednum = num.replace('.', '}');
//Replacing all ',' to '.'  First Thing you want
transformednum = transformednum.replace(',', '.');
//Replacing all '}' to ','   Second thing you want 
transformednum = transformednum.replace('}', ',');
System.out.println(transformednum);
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

```
    String in = "12,345.6789";

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[,.]");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(in);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    while (m.find()) {
        m.appendReplacement(sb, m.group().equals(".") ? "," : ".");
    }

    m.appendTail(sb);

    System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Comment: The `StringBuilder` support has been added in Java 9. In older versions you would need `StringBuffer`. But when you are using Java 9 or newer, you can also use `Pattern.compile("[,.]").matcher( "123.456,789").replaceAll(mr -> mr.group().equals(".")? ",": ".")`.

Answer (score 0):

```
String::replaceAll(a, b)
```

can replace any occurrences of the substring `a` for the substring `b`.

However, to do the swap you need to apply this method three times, like so:

```
String number = "123,456.05";
number = number.replaceAll(",", "&").replaceAll(".", ",").replaceAll("&", ".");
```

Generally, to swap characters it's like this:

1. you replace the comma for a placeholder substring (can be anything, really)
2. you convert all the dots into commas
3. you convert the placeholders into dots.

If it wasn't for the placeholder, you'd end up with all commas.

```
number.replaceAll(",", ".").replaceAll(".", ",");
//this would transform commas into dots, then the same transformed commas would become commas again.
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using Streams:

```
static String swapChars(String str, String c1, String c2)
{
    return Stream.of(str.split(c1, -1))
          .map (elem -> elem.replace(c2, c1))
          .collect(Collectors.joining(c2));
}
```

Test:

```
for(String s : new String[] {"12,345.6789", "12.345,6789", ".", "1." ,"1,"})
    System.out.format("%s -> %s%n", s, swapChars(s, ",", ".") );
```

Output:

```
12,345.6789 -> 12.345,6789
12.345,6789 -> 12,345.6789
. -> ,
1. -> 1,
1, -> 1.
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `String::replace` as follows:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        // Tests
        System.out.println(swapCommaWithDot("1,123,345.6789"));
        System.out.println(swapCommaWithDot("1.123.345,6789"));
    }

    static String swapCommaWithDot(String n) {
        return n.replace(",", ",.").replace(".", ",").replace(",.", ".").replace(",,", ".");
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
1.123.345,6789
1,123,345.6789
```